# Script to copy completed rows, then clear certain fields and advance date field

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on a workbook to track employee evaluation completions.  When the completion date is entered and the checkbox in column K is checked, I want it to copy the row to the "completed" sheet, then on the original sheet: 1) advance the next due date (column I) by 1 year, 2) clear the completed date field (column J), and uncheck the checkbox (to reset the entry for the following year).

```
function onEdit(e) {
const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
const r = e.range;
if (src.getName() != "Due" || r.columnStart != 11 || r.rowStart == 1) return;
const dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Complete");
*/copies row to completed sheet/*  
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,10).copyTo(dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,10));
*/clears date completed field/*
e.range.offset(0,-1).clearContent();
*/adds 1 year to date - not working/*
const date = sheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex(),9).getValue();
const newdate = edate(date,12);
src.getRange(J).setValue(newdate);
*/unchecks box/*
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("Due!K:K").uncheck();
}
```

When I enter a date and check the box, it does copy the row to the completed sheet, clears the date completed field, and will uncheck the box if I move that line up, but it hangs at adding 1 year to the date.